# How to find vowels in given sting?

Tags: javascript, string

I have requirement like if the given string contains vowels it should print the founded vowels  , if it does not contain vowels it should print message like no vowels found.

```js
function findVowels(str) {
    const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
    const foundVowels = str.contains(vowels);

    if (foundVowels.length > 0) {
        console.log('Found vowels:', foundVowels.join(', '));
    } else {
        console.log('No vowels found.');
    }
}

const inputString = "Hello, World!";
findVowels(inputString);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: What ***exactly*** is your question? All you've done is tell us what your requirement is and then some code. What isn't working?

Comment: `string.contains` doesn't exist as the error states. You need [`string.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution for your requirement. You need to modify your code like below.

```js
function findVowels(str) {
    // Convert the string to lowercase to make the check case-insensitive
    str = str.toLowerCase();

    // Define an array of vowels
    const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];

    // Filter the characters in the string that are vowels
    const foundVowels = Array.from(str).filter(char => vowels.includes(char));

    if (foundVowels.length > 0) {
        console.log('Found vowels:', foundVowels.join(', '));
    } else {
        console.log('No vowels found.');
    }
}

// Example usage:
const inputString = "Hello, World!";
findVowels(inputString);
```